# asp.net web api json not returning when on server

Tags: asp.net, json, rest, asp.net-web-api

I've built a web api for my mobile app.  I test it on the localhost in browser and it returns json as expected, but whenever I host it on azure and hit the same URL I receive no data, but google network (developer console) in chrome says it has retrieved 408B of data, but no content shows up where the json should be present?

What could I not have configured correctly?

I have gone into the Global.ascx file and added the following line of code

```
 public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.EnableCors();
    }
```

and added the EnableCors attribute on top of the webapi controller class and set the prefix router too.

What am I missing?

Controller code see below for a snippet of it.  the database is an EF Code First generated from a database that already existed.  Please note.

```
 [EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
    [RoutePrefix("api/numbers")]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public class NumbersController : ApiController
    {
        private MegaMillions db = new MegaMillions();

        [HttpGet]
        public HttpResponseMessage Get()
        {
            return db.Numbers.Take(10).ToList();
        }

        // GET: api/Numbers
        public List<Number> GetNumbers()
        {
            return db.Numbers.ToList();
        }
}
```

if I can figure out how to get the list working the other CRUD operations will follow suit.

Answer (score 0):

```
[EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
[RoutePrefix("api/values")]
public class ValuesController : ApiController
{
    List<Doctor> doctors = new List<Doctor>(){ new Doctor { Id = 1, FirstName = "Carl Finch", LastName = "Finch" }, new Doctor { Id = 2, FirstName = "Carl", LastName = "Finch" } };
    // GET api/values/5
    [Route("Get")]
    public string Get()
    {
        return "This is my controller response";
    }

    [Route("GetNumbers")]
    public List<Doctor> GetNumbers()
    {
        return doctors;
    }
}
```

So after adding Routes to each method in the web api it worked just fine!

So remember declaring the RouterPrefix is NOT ENOUGH to get data, each method in a web api has to have a proper Router attribute.

Comment: Please someone edit this if I am mistaken, but I was able to receive data after testing on azure server.